# Adding ".js" extension using replace with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have to import statements

```
// other code...
import * as Foo from "../some/bar";
import { baz } from './dir/qux';
// other code...
```

and I want to add a `.js` extension to the end of each of the above files in single/double quotes like so

```
import * as Foo from "../some/bar.js";
import { baz } from './dir/qux.js';
```

in the entire code strings.

What would be the proper way to replace with Regex in JavaScript?

In `global` and `case` match

`str.replace(regexp, newSubstr|function)`

[String.replace docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't file extensions optional already, at least with Webpack, if there's only one file of that name in the folder, or something of the sort?

Comment: Have you tried writing any such regular expression yourself yet? Seems simple enough, you just need to look for lines that start with `import` and replace the string at the end

Comment: @CertainPerformance , I'm  not using bundlers, that is why asking the question. If it's simple enough, why don' t you show me as an answer and I investigate and decide to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

Find:
`/^(import[^\S\r\n].+?[^\S\r\n]from[^\S\r\n]*(["']))((?:(?!(?:\.js)?\2)[\S\s])+)(\2\s*;)/mg`

Replace:
`$1$3.js$4`

https://regex101.com/r/Obcf0S/1

Readable regex

```
 ^                             # BOL
 (                             # (1 start), Preamble
      import [^\S\r\n] .+? 
      [^\S\r\n] 
      from [^\S\r\n]* 
      ( ["'] )                      # (2), Delimiter
 )                             # (1 end)
 (                             # (3 start), Body
      (?:
           (?!
                (?: \.js )?
                \2 
           )
           [\S\s] 
      )+
 )                             # (3 end)
 ( \2 \s* ; )                  # (4), Postfix
```

Answer (score 2):

Find lines that start with `import` and contain a slash, followed by non-slash, non-period characters, with lookahead for `['"];?` to identify the end of the string and the line:

```js
const codeStr = `
// other code...
import * as Foo from "../some/bar";
import { baz } from './dir/qux';
import { bar } from './dir/bar.js';
// other code...
`;
console.log(
  codeStr.replace(/import .+\/[^\/\.]+(?=['"];?$)/gm, '$&.js')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution. You are also smart to add an extra feature to avoid the duplicated *js. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let match = /(import.*)("|');/g.exec(`import { baz } from './dir/qux';`)
```

Then you get the following list:

```
(3) ["import { baz } from './dir/qux';", "import { baz } from './dir/qux", "'", index: 0, input: "import { baz } from './dir/qux';", groups: undefined]
```

You just need to add .js between element 1 and 2.

```
match[1]+".js"+match[2]
```